# How to search by name on actionbar searchview android from api webservice?

Tags: java, android, api, android-actionbar

my android app not using sqlite database using directly from the api webservice.Now i want to search by username on actionbar searchview from api webservice example thewebservice mydomain.com/api/search/action=search&q= I already have ui but how i can do it.please help me sample code.
how i can test condition search and q from api.???

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setOnQueryTextListener%28android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener%29 query submit listener

Comment: I already finished for ui searchview on actionbar but I want to know how to get data with parameter from api service simple code.

Answer (score -1):

```
All you need to do is follows 
1. invoke the service call in search button click 
 For this there are many ways, start with the easiest one, one of them is as follows
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheHttpClient/article.html

2. Populate the result in list. 
Once you have got the response in form of json or string, you need to format data in form of string array and do as follows
mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mStringArray));
```